# function or method for repeated event in python / django

Tags: python, django

```
models:
from django.db import models

class datecrt(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stdate=models.DateField()
    sttime=models.TimeField()
    endate=models.DateField()

forms:
import datetime
from xml.dom.minidom import Attr
from django import forms
from .models import datecrt


class dateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=datecrt
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
            'stdate':forms.DateInput(
                attrs={'type':'date','class':'form-control'},
                format='%D-%m-%yy',
            ),
            'sttime':forms.TimeInput(
                attrs={'type':'time','class':'form-control'},
                format='%H:%M',
            ),
            'endate':forms.DateInput(
                attrs={'type':'date','class':'form-control'},
                format='%D-%m-%yy',
            )
        }

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(dateform,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['stdate'].imput_format=('%D-%m-%yy',)
        self.fields['sttime'].imput_format=('%H:%M',)
        self.fields['endate'].imput_format=('%D-%m-%yy',)

Views:
from unicodedata import name
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import dateform
from .models import datecrt


def datecr(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        form=dateform()
        return render(request, 'date.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form=dateform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/dateview')

def dateview(request):
    context={'dateview':datecrt.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'dateview.html',context)
```

When I create this booking on 1st of feb and end date will select as 5th of feb, my challenge is, created booking should display name, date, and time till 5th of feb automatically in dateview template, without me creating same for 2nd of feb, 3rd of feb till 5th of feb manually.

```
template:
<table class="table">
    <thead class="border-bottom font-weight-bold">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>stdate</td>
            <td>sttime</td>
            <td>endate</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for bkg in dateview %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{bkg.name}}</td>
            <td>{{bkg.stdate}}</td>
            <td>{{bkg.sttime}}</td>
            <td>{{bkg.endate}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have also added the view template where the output is shown.

Comment: Add template. We need to see how do you implement it there, because you have `stdate` and `endate`, which is enough for keeping the object shown for that time range.

Comment: @NixonSparrow I have added the template also.

Comment: @NixonSparrow how do i run a loop for this code, where i should get the same output for all the dates from 1st,2nd,3rd,4th and 5th.

Comment: And that loop from the question is not working? Cause it looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter information in your context. Just change `dateview.context` to that:

```
def dateview(request):
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    context = {'dateview': datecrt.objects.filter(stdate__lte=today, endate__gte=today)}
    return render(request, 'dateview.html', context)
```

It basically means, that `dateview` will include only `datecrt` objects with `stdate` `less than or equal to` (same as '<=') today's date and `endate` `greater than or equal to` (same as '>=') today's date. It will update the query for every site load.

I didn't include `Time` in this yet. I hope you can manage on your own from now :)